# Drupal 7 grouping of autocomplete suggestions

Tags: drupal, autocomplete, drupal-7

I have an *places* autocomplete textfield. With the core drupal autocomplete i am able to show suggestions of places.

Now i need to group these suggestions by type à la OS X spotlight. Example :

- Hotels (34)

  - Hotel 1
  - Hotel 2
  - ...
- Restaurants (65)

  - Restaurant 1
  - ...

How do i override drupal's autocomplete to achieve this ? Or should i build this independently from drupal's autocomplete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Reference: [http://bitnr.drupalgardens.com/content/autocomplete-callbacks-drupal-7-or-fun-dbqueryrange-and](http://web.archive.org/web/20111228073250/http://bitnr.drupalgardens.com/content/autocomplete-callbacks-drupal-7-or-fun-dbqueryrange-and))

I believe you only get to return a flat array, similar to D6.

I would solve this with jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing...autocomplete still needs some love : http://drupal.org/node/675446

Answer (score 0):

HI please check the link , i have posted my comments here with sample code
http://drupal.org/node/1197448